# What is the best practice for multiple trivial mutations in Vuex store?

Tags: vue.js, vuex

In my Vuex code, I have countless trivial mutations, like:

```js
setOption(state, payload) {
    state.option = payload;
}
```

With hundreds of similar lines of code, it doesn't look to be good. Any better option?

Comment: You asked this question 4 minutes ago and answered as well. If you already know the answer then why this question ?

Comment: I failed to find this question on SO, and it took a while to find an answer, so I decided to share my findings. Moreover, I found two more options while I was writing an answer, so there is also a probability I've missed something else. BTW, Q&A format is encouraged by SO, so you can provide and answer simultaneously with the question, I just used this option.

Answer (score 2):

## Option 0 (New Recommended)

Consider switching to [Pinia](https://vuejs.org/guide/scaling-up/state-management.html#pinia), new official state manager for Vue.

Mutations do not exist any more. These can be converted to actions instead, or you can just assign directly to the store within your components (eg. `userStore.firstName = 'FirstName'`)

## Option 1 (Old Recommended)

Keep it this way.

Pros:

- Standard, well-documented.
- IDE support. You can easily find usages of some mutation across your project.
- Easy to add more logic when needed, e.g. age should be a positive number, etc...

Cons:

- Might look repetitive, so it is easier to skip some non-trivial mutation. However, this can partly be solved by convention to put all trivial to the end of the file\section, as soon as mutation stops to be non-trivial - move it to the top of the file\section.

## Option 2

Use a [universal mutation](https://www.jenniferbland.com/how-to-greatly-simplify-your-vuex-store/) :

```js
mutate(state, payload) {
   state[payload.property] = payload.with;
}
```

and call it:

```js
commit('mutate', {
    property: <propertyNameHere>,
    with: <valueGoesHere>
});
```

Pros:

- Clean mutation section, non-trivial mutations are visually distinct.

Cons:

- A little harder to find related mutations, e.g. some can have two or more spaces after `property:`
- More writing for each mutation call.
- Not really compatible with a standard way, so you can end with non-trivial mutation with additional logic, but someone can miss it and use a unified mutation call.

## Option 3

Use some code generator, e.g. [Hygen](https://www.hygen.io/)

Pros:

- You have the same code as from Option 1, including IDE support and future extension.
- You can set it to add in all places by a single command line - to state, mutation, and action (if needed).
- With typescript you also need to change interface of the store, wich can also be done with the same command line.

Cons:

- Can be hard to set up.
- Need additional informing of new team members.

## Option 4

Use some Vuex plugin with predefined mutations, e.g. [this one](https://github.com/mesqueeb/vuex-easy-access)

Pros:

- Minimal setup.
- Clean mutation section, non-trivial mutations are visually distinct.

Cons:

- Needs some knowledge about the plugin.
- A little harder to find related mutations
- Not really compatible with a standard way, so you can end with non-trivial mutation with additional logic, but someone can miss it and use a mutation call provided by a plugin.

Comment: Option 5? Found https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields which looks to be quite popular, still needs to evaluate it.